# how to set the eighth bit to zero (reading data from smarcard)

Tags: java, smartcard

How to set the eighth bit to zero? Sometimes I get incorrect le. What is wrong with p1, p2?

```
CommandAPDU(cla, ins, p1, p2, ne);
```

```
                CommandAPDU readBinaryAPDU = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB0, offset >> 8, offset & 0xFF, 0xff);
```

```
    public byte[] readCard(ResponseAPDU responseAPDU, CardChannel channel, byte[] fid, FidAdjusted fidEnum) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offset = 0;
        try {
            System.out.println("Reading: " + fidEnum.name());
            if ((fid[0] != 0x00 && fid[1] != 0x05) && (fid[0] != 0x00 && fid[1] != 0x02)) {
                //select MF - Solo para posicionarse
                //AID: ‘FF 54 41 43 48 4F’ dla aplikacji tacho 1. gen
                //AID: ‘FF 53 4D 52 44 54’ dla aplikacji tacho 2. gen
                CommandAPDU SELECT_MF = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x0C, OperationHelper.hexToByteAr("ff,54,41,43,48,4f"), 0x00, 0x06);
                responseAPDU = channel.transmit(SELECT_MF);
                System.out.println("Command select MF response: " + Integer.toHexString(responseAPDU.getSW1()));
            }
            // select EF
            CommandAPDU SELECT_EF = new CommandAPDU(0x00, APDUCommand.SELECT_FILE.getCommand(), 0x02, 0x0C, fid, 0x00, 0x02);
            responseAPDU = channel.transmit(SELECT_EF);
            System.out.println("Command select EF response: " + Integer.toHexString(responseAPDU.getSW1()));
            System.out.println("Begin reading... for " + fidEnum.name());
            do {
                // read binary
                CommandAPDU readBinaryAPDU = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB0, offset >> 8, offset & 0xFF, 0xff);
                responseAPDU = channel.transmit(readBinaryAPDU);
                int sw1 = responseAPDU.getSW1();
                baos.write(responseAPDU.getData());
                switch (sw1) {
                    case 0x90: {
                        System.out.println("(Good)" + Integer.toHexString(sw1));
                        offset += responseAPDU.getData().length;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 0x67: {
                        System.out.println("(incorrect Lc or Le) (Wrong) " + Integer.toHexString(sw1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (responseAPDU.getData().length == 0xff);
            System.out.println("Reading end: " + fidEnum.name());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

[image: Read binary]
[image]

[image]

[image]
Console output:

```
Begin reading... for EF_ICC
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_ICC
5
Reading: EF_IC
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_IC
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_IC
12032
Reading: EF_DIR
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 6a
Begin reading... for EF_DIR
Reading end: EF_DIR
1280
1281
Reading: EF_APPLICATION_IDENTIFICATION
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_APPLICATION_IDENTIFICATION
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_APPLICATION_IDENTIFICATION
49408
Reading: EF_CARD_CERTIFICATE
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_CARD_CERTIFICATE
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_CARD_CERTIFICATE
49416
Reading: EF_CA_CERTIFICATE
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_CA_CERTIFICATE
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_CA_CERTIFICATE
1312
Reading: EF_IDENTIFICATION
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_IDENTIFICATION
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_IDENTIFICATION
1294
Reading: EF_CARD_DOWNLOAD
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_CARD_DOWNLOAD
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_CARD_DOWNLOAD
1313
Reading: EF_DRIVING_LICENSE_INFO
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_DRIVING_LICENSE_INFO
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_DRIVING_LICENSE_INFO
1282
Reading: EF_EVENTS_DATA
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_EVENTS_DATA
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_EVENTS_DATA
1283
Reading: EF_FAULTS_DATA
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_FAULTS_DATA
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_FAULTS_DATA
1284
Reading: EF_DRIVER_ACTIVITY_DATA
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_DRIVER_ACTIVITY_DATA
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_DRIVER_ACTIVITY_DATA
1285
Reading: EF_VEHICLES_USED
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_VEHICLES_USED
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_VEHICLES_USED
1286
Reading: EF_PLACES
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_PLACES
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_PLACES
1287
Reading: EF_CURRENT_USAGE
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_CURRENT_USAGE
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_CURRENT_USAGE
1288
Reading: EF_CONTROL_ACTIVITY_DATA
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_CONTROL_ACTIVITY_DATA
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_CONTROL_ACTIVITY_DATA
1314
Reading: EF_SPECIFIC_CONDITIONS
Command select MF response: 90
Command select EF response: 90
Begin reading... for EF_SPECIFIC_CONDITIONS
(Good)90
(incorrect Lc lub Le) (Wrong) 67
Reading end: EF_SPECIFIC_CONDITIONS

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should try to reduce the question to as single topic. In any case P1/P2 together specify the starting offset within a binary file. With ISO 7816-4 READ BINARY you are restricted to to the first 32 kByte due to bit 8 of P1=0. Your protocol should give SW1 AND SW2 from the card response (instead of SW1 only), since 6A alone may mean much different causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the eighth bit to zero, your bit mask has to be 0111 1111 in binary, that's 0x7F in hex.

```
offset & 0x7F
```

I don't know what your code does but if the 3rd and 4th parameters to CommandAPDU are supposed to have only the last 7 bits set, apply the mask.

```
new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB0, (offset >> 8) & 0x7F, offset & 0x7F, 0xff);
```

Comment: This code should read binary data from truck driver card (tachograph). Documentation is available here https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32002R1360&from=en I can't find how should change p1, p2

Comment: So what should I use (P1,P2, le, LC etc) for read binary data according documentation?

Answer (score 0):

For `READ BINARY` P1 and P2 represent the start offset, with P1 being the most significant byte. From that offset within the file data are retrieved.

If your offset is >= 0x8000, this is an error for instruction code 0xB0 (because then P1 would be interpreted as short EF identifier instead). (Consequentially 32 kByte is an important size limit.)

The most significant bit of P2 has no special meaning, therefore masking it has no benefit besides getting other data than expected. (I would consider this as bug.)

For details, as always, refer to ISO 7816, part 4.